# Using countifs with Index function and (OR) criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm using this formula to count rows that has either of the following text (SCD,SCA,Sickl).
First I indexed two columns to be one column (E & G)
Then I asked to count any row that has any one of the following texts (*SCD* or *SCA* or *sickl*). if the column has two of three of those texts, It will all return same count 1 as one row only.

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(countif(index(admissions!E9:E58 & admissions!G9:G58),{"*SCD*","*SCA*","*Sickl*"})))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUk3hUwL2CcePR4aKXU746DQTVdTVE5_lICpYSKBLpg/edit?usp=sharing

This is the link, the formula gives back a result of 6 while it should have given 4 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(1*REGEXMATCH(UPPER(admissions!E9:E58 & admissions!G9:G58),"SCD|SCA|SICKL")))`

`REGEXMATCH` will see if any of the elements separated by the pipe symbol are in the search range.

`UPPER` assures uniformity (so that lowercase, mixed-case or uppercase matches will count as a match)

The results would normally return as a list of TRUE or FALSE (depending on if a match is found). So adding `1*` is a way to turn those into 1s and 0s respectively.

`SUM`, of course, SUMS those 1s and 0s.

Comment: It worked after capitalizing the word "SICKL" . Great

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. I missed that "Sickl" wasn't originally all-caps. Glad you caught that. I fixed it in the post.

Comment: What if I didn't add "1*" or in other words 
{REGEXMATCH(UPPER(admissions!E9:E58 & admissions!G9:G58),"SCD|SCA|SICKL")} what does it return as a result?

Comment: The Boolean values TRUE and FALSE alone would return 0 inside SUM( ), because SUM ignores all data types other than real numbers.